# VB.NET 2010 and SQL Server 2008 with ADO.NET Proplem

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ado.net

**Hi !
I am try to build a system for library in Visual Basic
I designed the database by SQL server
so i joined two table to gather
so how can I insert / delete / update buttons ?!
by using DataSet because it used when I have two table and more ?
I searched a lot but I can't find the answer :(
so please help me in my project !**

Answer (score 0):

SQLCommandBuilder cannot handle Select statements with joins. You can build your own Update, Delete and Insert statements and add them to the DataAdapter. Parameters must be mapped.

Another approach is to have 2 DataTables in your DataSet and use relationships to accomplish the features of a join.

A third approach is to abandon the DataAdapter and bind directly to your DataTable. Then use RowState and loops to change the Database. This is what the DataAdapter is doing internally. I think this is the simplest. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/row-states-and-row-versions

I usually provide a bit of code but since you didn't; I won't. Try one or all of these suggestions and if you have problems, post again with the code you have tried.